# Is there any way to convert Excel formula to PostgreSQL formula database?

Tags: excel, postgresql

I have this excel formula which contain values.

H13 = 425,
T13 = -17%

Excel Formula

```
      =IF(H13<>"",IF(H13<0,H13*(1-$T13),H13*(1+$T13)),"")
```

Output Value after excel calculation is :

```
       352
```

I tried with [SQLIZER] https://sqlizer.io/ but not working only provide Insert query.

Comment: The obvious way is to understand the logic, then write it using the new language.

Comment: If you know the excel formula it will be easy

Comment: So what do you think the excel formula does? Hint: break it into steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in text form:

if H13 is not blank then do:

```
   IF H13 < 0, calculate H13 * (1 - T13)

   else calculate:  H13 * (1 + T13)
```

else do: blank

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the formula so it's easier to convert to SQL: `H13 + (ABS(H13) * $T13)`

Comment: Did you check this? Did you test the output against the original, using the stated values?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check against the stated values. I've corrected it now from abs(H13*$T13) to (abs(H13)*$T13)

Answer (score 0):

I have try some postgres case function and it is working.

```
case when a.target !=0 
             then 
             case when a.target<0 
                    then a.target*(100-to_number(regexp_replace(b.sbt_pet,'%',''), '99G999D9S'))/100
                    else 
                           a.target*(100+to_number(regexp_replace(b.sbt_pet,'%',''), '99G999D9S'))/100
             end
       else a.target
end as calculated_sb
```